# c++ opengl: how to find normalized vectors for a quad?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, geometry, normalization

can anyone assist me in finding the proper formula for quad normalization ?

using c++ with opengl.

thank you!

Comment: Do you want to normalize a vector or do you want to compute the normal vector to a plane?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you want the normal vector for a quad, this pseudo-code works

```
Vector3d vertex[4] = { ... }
Vector3d normal(0,0,0) ;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    normal += cross (vertex[i], vertex[(i+1)%4]) ; // cross product
}
normalize (normal) ;
// normal is the unit normal to the quad
```

This gives you the formula `n=A/|A|`, where `A = v0xv1 + v1xv2 + v2xv3 + v3xv0` and  `vi=vertex[i]`). `|A|/2` is also the area of the polygon. This can be generalized to arbitrary polygons, and will even give reasonable results for non-planar polygons, as long as they aren't too non-planar.

One reference is http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0101/algorithm_0101.htm

If you know that the quad/polygon is planar, you only have to calculate the normal of the triangle formed by the first three vertices.  This is `A1/|A1|`, where `A1 = (v1-v0)x(v2-v0) = v0xv1 + v1xv2 + v2xv0`.

If by "quad normalization" you meant something else, just ignore this answer.

EDIT: I found this related question: [Get the Surface Area of a Polyhedron (3D object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350604/get-the-area-of-a-3d-surface)

Comment: shouldn't you subtract 2 of the vertices to get a vector? Taking the cross product of points isn't useful for normals.

Comment: why the for loop and why the modulo?

Comment: @cobbal, you can do it with edge vectors like (v_1 - v_0) x (v_2 - v_0), but once you simplify it it ends up being something like
 `v0xv1 + v1xv2 + v2Xv0`.  @sisis, the modulo give you the `v0` in the last term.

Comment: I'm loading dxf files that are build from quads and drawing them on the screen, i want to find their normals so I'll have proper lighting

Comment: You're missing a ']' in "normal += cross (vertex[i], vertex[(i+1)%4) ;"  I think it should be "normal += cross (vertex[i], vertex[(i+1)%4]) ;" ... ?

Comment: Right on.  Fixed.  It would be nice if SO had a way of checking for balanced parentheses :)

Answer (score 8):

Newell's method is usually your best choice for computing the normals of polygons which are nearly planar. It tends to be fairly robust to minor irregularities without being too expensive. See the [Graphics Gems article](http://books.google.com/books?id=xmW_u3mQLmQC&lpg=PA231&ots=Z5-1NPHaMh&dq=newell's%20method%20polygon%20normal&pg=PA231#v=onepage&q=newell's%20method%20polygon%20normal&f=false). It's similar to that described above:

```
Vector3d normal(0,0,0) ;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    int j = (i+1)%4;
    normal.x += (vertex[i].y - vertex[j].y)
               *(vertex[i].z + vertex[j].z);
    normal.y += (vertex[i].z - vertex[j].z)
               *(vertex[i].x + vertex[j].x);
    normal.z += (vertex[i].x - vertex[j].x)
               *(vertex[i].y + vertex[j].y);
}
normalize (normal) ;
```

It's probably not going to matter much for quads if they're reasonably well behaved, but I would certainly use it if you're dealing with more complex polygons.