# Boost Geometry correct

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

is there an opportunity in boost 1.52.0 to correct a 3d polygon? 
With `point_xy` it works great, but not with a `point<double, double, double>` in 3d.
Or should I test the orientation myself?

Thx

Comment: I had tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2350800/2081805) but it has not the same result as ``correct``

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question. As it is now, you don't even explain what you mean with "correcting" a 3D polygon. It's impossible to answer.